# How can I find the first start time within various sequences of events?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following columns

`VehicleId`,`StatusId`,`StartTime`,`Comments`

The data is basically a sequence of changes to `VehicleId`,`StatusId` with the time they occurred and comments. Each vehicle can have a statusid occur many times in the last few years. The data spans a period of years, but isn't a huge dataset 50000 rows. We only are interested in datetime of each change of status for each vehicle.  So that would mean that I have many combinations of vehicle and statusid and the first start date seen in sequence. So a vehicle had a `StatusId` in two different sequences I would want the earliest date of each sequence, the `VehicleId` and that `StatusId`. How can I get that?

I created a sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/858a9/2)

I looked at  `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [VehicleId],[StatusID]  ORDER BY StartTime) AS [Group]` etc but they don't seem to help

Input

```
VehicleId  | StatusId | StartTime
      1    |     1    | 2010-1-1
      1    |     1    | 2010-1-2
      1    |     2    | 2010-1-3
      1    |     2    | 2010-1-4
      1    |     1    | 2010-1-5
      2    |     1    | 2010-1-2
```

Output

```
VehicleId  | StatusId | FirstStartTime
      1    |     1    | 2010-1-1
      1    |     2    | 2010-1-3
      1    |     1    | 2010-1-5
      2    |     1    | 2010-1-2
```

So I basically need to reduce the output rows to only have the start of each sequence ingoring any changes to the row unless it is a change in VehcileId or StatusId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can identify the groups using a difference of row numbers approach.  Then aggregation gets what you want:

```
select vehicleId, statusId, min(StartTime) as FirstStartTime
from (select se.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by vehicleId  order by StartTime) -
              row_number() over (partition by vehicleId, StatusId order by StartTime)
             ) as grp
      from StatusEvents se
     ) se
group by grp, statusId, vehicleId
order by vehicleId, FirstStartTime;
```

Comment: Great - does exactly what I need. Difference of row numbers approach isn't something i have seen before! Will have to do some reading on it.